# Dual booting laptop with new UEFI windows 10 and linux mint taken from old SSD of a dead laptop with MBR

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, linux-mint, dualboot

I've got an old laptop ssd (with linux mint installation) that I am trying to dual boot with a newer laptop running windows 10. Problem is Windows is UEFI whereas SSD is using MBR as it is from an old laptop circa 2009.

After inserting the SSD into the new laptop, I tried booting into it by setting BIOS to legacy boot method instead of UEFI boot, it went to GRUB rescue prompt.
After trying the following

```
grub rescue> ls
grub rescue> set boot=(hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

I was able to boot to linux mint, but I observed that boot was very slow. It opened a saved session from long time and everything was dead slow (10x slow considering this is an SSD). My old laptop felt faster compared to this.

So now I have reverted back to UEFI boot in BIOS and was able to boot back in.
My question is, how can I setup this dual boot properly? I am using Lenovo Ideapad gaming 3 laptop.

Comment: The way to set it up properly is to **reinstall Linux**, end of story. Although you can install Grub for UEFI in the Mint you already have this is really a 'hack' that should be avoided. Clean everything *including* the partitioning table - you want GPT instead of 'msdos' (MBR) - and properly install Mint in UEFI mode.